# Converting functions to log space

Tags: math, logarithm

I have to implement a couple of functions, specifically:

[image: functions]

Issue is that I have the log(p) values to prevent underflow. How do I convert those functions to have their values be in log space?

I know for the products of p, I can convert that to sums of log(p) but I'm not sure about the others. Thanks.

My attempt in order:

log(1 - 10^log(p1))

1- prod_i,n(1 - log(pi)) Not sure??

sum_i,n(log(pi))

sum_i,n(log(pi)^wti)

sum_i,n(log(pi))/n

sum_i,n(wti*log(pi))/sum_i,n(wti)

Comment: @chux Do I need to? p is very small (user input) so I log the value that way I can do things such as multiplying p1 with p2 with p3.

Comment: @chux ok I edited to include my attempt.

Comment: I think you may be looking for a function that adds two values in log space, commonly known as `logadd` e.g. `double logadd (double a, double b) {double t; if (b > a) { t = b; b = a; a = t; } t = b - a; return a + log1p (exp (t)); }`? In log space, multiplication turns into addition, and division turns into subtraction, so that part is trivial.